# Weak*-complemented subspaces of $\ell_\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider $\ell_\infty$ as $\ell_1^*$. Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional complemented subspace of $\ell_\infty$ (in partiuclar, $X$ is isomorphic to $\ell_\infty$). Can we find a further subspace $Y\subset X$ which is still isomorphic to $\ell_\infty$ but it is also range of a weak*-weak* continuous projection on $\ell_\infty$?

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: The problem is difficult.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Is it an interrogation or something? I simply don't know how to tackle this.

Comment: @JanBazyl good question (+1). ***Do not close it!***

Comment: @Shaun, there is no need for being rude here. If you do not even know how to start the problem, just write this in your post.

Comment: I am interested in this problem.  Where does it come from?  Is it a homework exercise?  Part of some research?  Idle curiosity?

Comment: I am reading one of Rosenthal's papers and if this were true, some of his arguments could be simplified.

Comment: @JanBazyl, then it is probably not true :)

Comment: @JanBazyl I'm sorry if I seemed rude. It wasn't intended. I was just asking for a bit of context (like Ben) :)